# Checking Encryption handshake using Wireshark for SQL connection over SSL

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssl, fips

I have implemented a secure SSL connection on the SQL Server 2005 server.  I use the "Microsoft SQL Server Management studio" to connect to the SQL Server and I check the "Encrypt Connection" check box in the options section.  The connection is successful and when I look at the connection properties in the mgmt studio, it shows me "Encrypted=Yes".
So that tells me that my SSL setup is correct and I'm able to successfully connect my management studio to sql server on a secure SSL encryption channel.

**Question**

I want to find out what "security functions" are being used behind the scenes on this connection...because I want to make sure it complies with one of the approved standards by 
fips 140-2 anex a (http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips140-2/fips1402annexa.pdf), which has information on approved encryption functions

So I used wireshark to capture the traffic and find out the protocols/handshakes.  For instance something like 'Auth TLS' request etc...

But I couldn't find out any of the encryption related information (I guess don't know how to).  I don't see any SSL protocol packets.  Maybe its doing all the encryption stuff at some other protocol level.

So how I do go about figuring this out?  I have the packet capture from wireshark and I can provide it to whoever is interested in looking at it.  stackoverflow probably doesnt allow attachments.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to enter `ssl` as the Wireshark filter to show only SSL and TLS packets, and you should see the client and server handshake and exchange a list of ciphers.  If the client initiates any SSL connection, you should see a CLIENT HELLO somewhere in your capture.  You can show only these packets with the filter `ssl.handshake.type == 1`.

That being said, running SQL Server 2005 SP1+ in FIPS 140-2 mode is covered by KB article [920995](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920995).  From what you wrote, it sounds like you are just hoping the client and server pick an allowed cipher, but that's not how FIPS 140-2 works.  Even if your session chooses an allowed cipher, it may not choose a *FIPS-certified* cipher, and the certification is what's important.

The KB article spells it out with this quote:

> Note that it is not sufficient to use
>   an algorithm from the approved lists
>   in FIPS 140-2. It is necessary to use
>   an instance of such an algorithm that
>   has been certified.

To guarantee the server uses a FIPS-certified cipher, you need to enable the FIPS 140-2 policy like the KB article says.

Comment: @indiv : I entered ssl in the search field of wireshark. I am able to view the handhshake process and the encrypted data etc. But I am not able to view the encrypted key during keyexchange. How can I view the encrypted key(during the procees of key exchange 252 - client key exchange) in wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

not using wireshark but using netmon, i have a write up on doing this here: 
http://cornasdf.blogspot.com/2010/04/sql-server-data-in-transit-cipher.html

Answer (score 0):

Using Wireshark, you can easily find whether the connection is encrypted by looking at the packet data. This document explains the analysis clearly => https://middlewareworld.org/2020/09/04/step-by-step-ssl-handshake-with-wireshark/